# Want to make zipcode text field as a "required" field on my product page of magento site

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart, zipcode

My website bookslab.in is almost ready. I am selling the books online. Now i am stuck on this problem. I want to make the zipcode field on my product page as a "required" field before users add the products in the shopping cart by clicking on "add to cart" button. I want to make every users to check their zipcode first then add the products in the cart, because i am delivering the books in limited areas. I am proving the cod.phtml file as a code. Please suggest any solution in my provided code, if you want any code you can comment me.

cod.phtml

```
<?php
/***************************************
 *** Cash On Delivery ***
 ***************************************[![enter image description here][1]][1]/

$msgData = Mage::helper('netgo_cod')->getConfigData(); 
if($msgData['zip_status'] == 1){
?>
<div class="input-box">
    <div class="z-btn">
        <label>Zip Code : </label><input type="text" placeholder="Enter your pincode" value="" name="cod" class="product-custom-option" id="cod" size="29" style='color:black; font-size:12px' required>
        <button type="button" onclick="checkCOD();" name="zip-check" title="Check" class="button" id="zip-check"><span><span>Check</span></span></button>
    </div>
    <div id="cod_msg"></div>
</div>

<script>
    function checkCOD(){
        var cod = $('cod').value;
        if(cod == ''){
            $('cod_msg').update('<span class="cod-error"><?php echo $msgData['emp_msg']; ?></span>');
            return
        }else{
            $('cod_msg').update('<img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl( Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB, true ).'media/cod/img/ajax-loader-2.gif';?>">'); 
            new Ajax.Request('<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl().'netgo/cod/check';?>', {
                method:'post',
                parameters: {zipcode: cod}, 
                onSuccess: function(transport) {
                    var response = transport.responseText || "no response text";
                    $('cod_msg').update(response);
                },
                onFailure: function() { alert('Something went wrong...'); }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

---

cod.phtml

```
<?php
/***************************************
 *** Cash On Delivery ***
 ***************************************
 *
 */

$msgData = Mage::helper('netgo_cod')->getConfigData(); 
if($msgData['zip_status'] == 1){
?>
<div class="input-box">
    <div class="z-btn">
        <label>Zip Code : </label><input type="text" placeholder="Enter your pincode" value="" name="cod" class="product-custom-option required-entry" id="cod" size="29" style='color:black; font-size:12px'>
        <button type="button" onclick="checkCOD();" name="zip-check" title="Check" class="button" id="zip-check"><span><span>Check</span></span></button>
    </div>
    <div id="cod_msg"></div>
</div>

<script>
    function checkCOD(){
             var zipcode;
        var cod = $('cod').value;
        if(cod == ''){
            $('cod_msg').update('<span class="cod-error"><?php echo $msgData['emp_msg']; ?></span>');
            return
        }else{
            $('cod_msg').update('<img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl( Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB, true ).'media/cod/img/ajax-loader-2.gif';?>">'); 
            new Ajax.Request('<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl().'netgo/cod/check';?>', {
                method:'post',
                parameters: {zipcode: cod}, 
                onSuccess: function(transport) {
                    var response = transport.responseText || "no response text";
                    $('cod_msg').update(response);

                    if(response.search('Delivery of the book is not available on the above pincode')!=-1)
                                        {
                                          zipcode='checked';
                                        }
                                      else
                                      {
                                      zipcode='';
                                      }

                },
                onFailure: function() { alert('Something went wrong...'); }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

---

view.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 *
 * @see Mage_Review_Block_Product_View
 */
?>
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
</script>
<div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?></div>
<div class="product-view">
    <div class="product-essential">
        <form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product, array('_secure' => $this->_isSecure())) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
            <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
            <div class="no-display">
                <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />
            </div>

            <div class="product-img-box">
                <div class="product-name">
                    <h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
                </div>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>
            </div>

            <div class="product-shop">
                <div class="product-name">
                    <span class="h1"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></span>
                </div>

                <div class="price-info">
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product); ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('bundle_prices') ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
                </div>

                <div class="extra-info">
                    <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'default', false)?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_availability'); ?>
                </div>

                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>

                <?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?>
                    <div class="short-description">
                        <div class="std"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?></div>
                    </div>
                <?php endif;?>




                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('other');?>

                <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
                <?php endif;?>

            </div>

            <div class="add-to-cart-wrapper">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>

                <?php if (!$this->hasOptions()):?>
                    <div class="add-to-box">
                        <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
                            <?php if( $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() || $_compareUrl=$this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product)): ?>
                                <span class="or"><?php echo $this->__('OR') ?></span>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('sharing') ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_buttons') ?>
                <?php elseif (!$_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <div class="add-to-box">
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('sharing') ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>

            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('related_products') ?>

            <div class="clearer"></div>
            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
            <?php endif;?>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
            var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
            productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
                if (this.validator.validate()) {
                    var form = this.form;
                    var oldUrl = form.action;

                    if (url) {
                       form.action = url;
                    }
                    var e = null;
                    try {

                    if(zipcode=='checked')
                    {
                       this.form.submit();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       alert('check zipcode');
                    }


                    } catch (e) {
                    }
                    this.form.action = oldUrl;
                    if (e) {
                        throw e;
                    }

                    if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                        button.disabled = true;
                    }
                }
            }.bind(productAddToCartForm);

            productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function(button, url){
                if(this.validator) {
                    var nv = Validation.methods;
                    delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
                    delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
                    delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
                    // Remove custom datetime validators
                    for (var methodName in Validation.methods) {
                        if (methodName.match(/^validate-datetime-.*/i)) {
                            delete Validation.methods[methodName];
                        }
                    }

                    if (this.validator.validate()) {
                        if (url) {
                            this.form.action = url;
                        }
                        this.form.submit();
                    }
                    Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
                }
            }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
        //]]>
        </script>
    </div>

    <div class="product-collateral toggle-content tabs">
        <?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
            <dl id="collateral-tabs" class="collateral-tabs">
                <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $alias => $html):?>
                    <dt class="tab"><span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getChildData($alias, 'title')) ?></span></dt>
                    <dd class="tab-container">
                        <div class="tab-content"><?php echo $html ?></div>
                    </dd>
                <?php endforeach;?>
            </dl>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_additional_data') ?>

</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. Checking the ZIP and if it the wrong one give an error? What is your exact problem? What have you tried and doesn't work as expected?

Comment: Yeah the problem is:

Comment: When zipcode is invalid the message pop up "your zip code is invalid" after that when user clicks on add to cart button the product directly added in the shopping cart which is a bug. The zipcode is invalid and still product is added in the shopping cart. I want if zip code is valid then only product should be added in the shopping cart.

Comment: Any answer stacky's to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you have to check condition is zipcode is checked or not.

**File :** app/design/frontend/(your_package_name)/(your_theme_name)/template/catalog/product/ view.phtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
        productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
            if (this.validator.validate()) {
                var form = this.form;
                var oldUrl = form.action;

                if (url) {
                   form.action = url;
                }
                var e = null;
                try {
         // **************add this part**************
                    if(zipcode=='checked')
                    {
                       this.form.submit();
                    }else
                    {
                       alert('check zipcode');
                    }
         //**************till here*********************
                } catch (e) {
                }
                this.form.action = oldUrl;
                if (e) {
                    throw e;
                }

                if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                    button.disabled = true;
                }
            }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);

        productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function(button, url){
            if(this.validator) {
                var nv = Validation.methods;
                delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
                delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
                delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
                if (this.validator.validate()) {
                    if (url) {
                        this.form.action = url;
                    }
                    this.form.submit();
                }
                Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
            }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
    //]]>
    </script>
```

Add variable **zipcode** and set it as **checked** on success in your file `cod.phtml`

```
<?php
/***************************************
 *** Cash On Delivery ***
 ***************************************[![enter image description here][1]][1]/

$msgData = Mage::helper('netgo_cod')->getConfigData(); 
if($msgData['zip_status'] == 1){
?>
<div class="input-box">
    <div class="z-btn">
        <label>Zip Code : </label><input type="text" placeholder="Enter your pincode" value="" name="cod" class="product-custom-option" id="cod" size="29" style='color:black; font-size:12px' required>
        <button type="button" onclick="checkCOD();" name="zip-check" title="Check" class="button" id="zip-check"><span><span>Check</span></span></button>
    </div>
    <div id="cod_msg"></div>
</div>

<script>
    function checkCOD(){

      // **************add this part**************
        var zipcode;
     // ***************************************

        var cod = $('cod').value;
        if(cod == ''){
            $('cod_msg').update('<span class="cod-error"><?php echo $msgData['emp_msg']; ?></span>');
            return
        }else{
            $('cod_msg').update('<img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl( Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB, true ).'media/cod/img/ajax-loader-2.gif';?>">'); 
            new Ajax.Request('<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl().'netgo/cod/check';?>', {
                method:'post',
                parameters: {zipcode: cod}, 
                onSuccess: function(transport) {
                    var response = transport.responseText || "no response text";
                    $('cod_msg').update(response);

         // **************add this part**************
                    if(response.search('Delivery of the book is not available on the above pincode')!=-1)
                    {
                       zipcode='checked';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       zipcode='';
                    }

         //*****************************************

                },
                onFailure: function() { alert('Something went wrong...'); }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

**Note :**

It will allow add to cart only on success of zipcode. If you want to allow add to cart on any other condition then you have to add condition accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your logic, but its not worked nothing happening. Is there any way that to change "add to cart" button to "view details" button when i search all books on my website.

Comment: @user1764289 yes replace add to cart button with view detail button and provide anchor to product detailed page.

Comment: Okzz i had done that, so now i had found one more bug, when users place invalid zipcode in the textfield & after that they click on add to cart button, so are successful to add the products in the shopping cart, which is not good, I need an exception for this bug.

Comment: @user1764289 Code updated. EDIT:  if(response=='REPLACE WITH YOUR SUCCESS MESSAGE'){ zipcode='checked'; }

Comment: @user1764289 if this helful to you then mark it as answer and close the question.

Comment: I will check and update you

Comment: I had checked it, the product is still being added in the shopping cart if the zipcode it wrong.

Comment: @user1764289 please provide the values of variable 'transport' in each case . like in case of success and in case of failure.

Comment: can you explain me in the code i provided, or do you want any different code.

Comment: Provide netgo/controller/cod.php in question

Comment: the above code is the  netgo/controller/cod.php

Comment: Any answer to this question? it is urgent stacky's

Comment: Above one is template file code.phtml. I want controller file code.php.

Comment: I don't have any cod.php file in my directory.

Comment: There is link of controller in ajax request. If you are new in Magento then please get the basic of Magento. If you want it urgent then hire any freelancer.

Comment: NO i am not new to magento the requested file is not present in our directories of magento, do u want any file other than this

Comment: @SalmanDalal i have seen you website http://www.bookslab.in/  . As you have not updated text for 'REPLACE WITH YOUR SUCCESS MESSAGE' and also not updated code in view.phtml.  I have updated my answer just check it once.

Comment: Okkz i will check that

Comment: I just check that by updating the code u had send me, still the books is being added in the shopping cart of the zip code is invalid

Comment: `if(zipcode=='checked')
                    {
                       this.form.submit();
                    }else
                    {
                       alert('check zipcode');
                    }`  still missing this part in your website. **File** app/design/frontend/base (or) rwd /default/templet/catalog/product/view.phtml

Comment: Now i had done the changes u instructed, now the button of add to cart is locked if the zipcode is invalid but message is not showing.

Comment: & if the zipcode is correct still the product is not adding in shopping cart. Add to cart button is not working now

Comment: Okzz i do one thing now i will upload the code which is edited by you. View.phtml & cod.phtml

Comment: I had uploaded the updated view.phtml & cod.phtml files that you suggested me

Comment: Now my add to cart button is not working plz check that

Comment: `if(zipcode=='checked') { this.form.submit(); }else { alert('check zipcode'); }` replace with ` this.form.submit(); ` nd raise your new question or update existing

Comment: Okzz i will check this

Comment: I had checked this, now my add to cart button is working but still the products has been added in the shopping cart if the zip code is invalid

Comment: Any answer to this question stacky's?

Answer (score 2):

add this in your class `required-entry`

```
<input type="text" class="product-custom-option required-entry" placeholder="Enter your pincode" value="" name="cod"  id="cod" size="29" style='color:black; font-size:12px'>
```

Comment: Thanks "user3046689" you rock! it works for me. But when message "This is a required field."  comes the button "check" of zip code field comes down it looks very weird. So is there any code to change the position of message  "This is a required field."

Comment: no you have to manage this from css according to your layout. If answer worked out for you pls accept it.

Comment: Whenever i search all books on my website there is a add to cart button below each book, so when i click on add to cart button the product directly goes in shopping cart, so how to stop this, because user does not checked its zipcode & product is directly added  in cart.